# PowerApps filter returning incomplete data record...?

Tags: sql, azure, powerapps

I have an Azure SQL database, and my records inside table **Spiderfood_RITMData** in that database includes 13 different fields. Lots of stuff. I have *confirmed* in SQL-SMS that the records have data in each field.

[image]

There are way more items in the database than PowerApps can see using LOOKUP (1600-9000 records or more). However, I know FOR A FACT that there is only ONE record that has any given value in the NUMBER column. It's not a primary key, but it is unique in the table.

In PowerApps, I am trying to pull that field so that I can eventually parse out the individual items.

So, the commands I'm trying are:

```
ClearCollect(MLE_test1, Filter('Spiderfood_RITMData', "RITM2170467" in Number));
ClearCollect(MLE_test2, Search('Spiderfood_RITMData',"RITM2170467", "Number"));
```

However, the Collection results for MLE_test1 and MLE_test2 both are empty *EXCEPT for the value of NUMBER*. Say what?!

[image]

I'm trying to use the examples posted on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-filter-lookup but I am honestly getting baffled by this.

How should I be formatting this call such that I can pull the whole record?

---

Big picture explanation:  I need to do a lot of data LOOKUPS into my table **Spiderfood_RITMData** table, but it has way more than 2000 rows, and PowerApps will not perform the Lookup correctly. So my presumably smart idea is to create a MUCH SMALLER "version" of **Spiderfood_RITMData** as a local collection, using a more delegateable function (such as FILTER or IN). If I filter by all records containing the values of NUMBER, then I go from, say a 10,000-record *SQL table* to a 10-record *Collection*. And I can do LOOKUPS against that collection for the rest of the function (uh, *I think* -- I'm still trying to experiment accordingly). Please let me know if this is crazy or not.

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, but there is a feature in Power Apps where it optimizes the network requests to only retrieve the columns that are used in the app. To test this hypothesis, try adding a label in your app with the Text property set to `First(MLE_test1).Name`, and click the button to populate the collection again. If the Name property is now filled, then this is the case, and as you start to use those properties, they will start showing up in your app.

Comment: I... I can't imagine a more annoying thing for PowerApps to do, if so. But it's useful to know that Microsoft's own website examples are wrong. :(

Answer (score 0):

LookUp is just used to get one record, instead try this:

```
ClearCollect(MLE_test1, Filter('Spiderfood_RITMData', "RITM2170467" = Number));
```

This gets a collection with all the items where Number is = to "RITM2170467"

Collections are limited to only 2000 records in each collections.

Comment: The target COLLECTION won't ever get more than, say, a dozen or so entries. But it's pulling those dozen or so entries from a SQL table that has as many as 9000 or so records. Prior to this, I have been using LOOKUP to pull directly from the SQL table, but the SQL table has grown larger, so I have to set up an intermediate stage.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue.  Go to App settings.  Under Upcoming Features make sure Explicit column selection is turned off.  Hope this does it for you.